# Why my boostrap 4.0 beta is not working properly?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I downloaded bootstrap 4.0 beta from getbootstrap.com, I included CSS & js from dist folder, but my styles are incomplete (navbar, hidden, visible are not working) do I need any extra stuff to include for my bootstrap folder,(do i need sass folder).
I included my css, js & jquery with correct path.
Can anyone help me with answer.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Page 1 <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Page 1-1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page 1-2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page 1-3</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign Up</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<div class="container">
  <h3>Collapsible Navbar</h3>
  <p>In this example, the navigation bar is hidden on small screens and replaced by a button in the top right corner (try to re-size this window).
  <p>Only when the button is clicked, the navigation bar will be displayed.</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you provide a minimal, reproducible example?

Comment: This should work just fine as long as you don't need the js part of BS. Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: grid systems are working fine, but navgation & some other classes are not supporting

Comment: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/migration/ ,
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navs/
these links might be helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned that you downloaded Bootstrap 4.0 beta, so I'm assuming you're trying to use the file path to use it. You do not need to download SASS. If you don't really need all its features then you can just follow Bootstraps 'quick start guide', https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <!-- Required meta tags -->
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

        <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">
      </head>
      <body>
        <h1>Hello, world!</h1>

        <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
        <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Just to get you started, try that. Then maybe later you can pick specific components.

Comment: Using CDN it is working fine but i dont want store bootstrap in server, i want to download locally & iam importing css, js and jquery file through link and script tag with exact path. is it wrong using file path

Comment: The issue is that you're using Bootstrap 3.x.x version. Bootstrap did a complete overhaul of their framework with 4.0 beta; for example, your still using glyphicon, but they've removed this component. Use the current documentation for your Navbar. Here is more info about the changes <https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/migration/>